# What prayers, Psalms or other items are commonly recited on Tu B'Av?

Tags: tefilla, 15th-of-av

During the past few days, my answering machine, local Jewish newspapers and my email inbox have been inundated with various requests to donate to organizations and / or rabbanim that will daven on Tu B'Av. Some have been a bit less "aggressive" by just encouraging me to daven on Tu B'Av (w/o asking for a huge monetary donation) for people that need *shidduchim*.

I'm in for the second idea as I personally know many people that need *shidduchim*. But, I'm not sure what prayers or Psalms are recommended. Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend, "O God, please get So-and-So a suitable spouse" or any other words with roughly the same meaning. I've no source, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but maybe someone else can find one (or I later).

Comment: The DailyTehillim.com website suggests Tehillim Chapters 32, 38, 70, 71, 121 and 124 for those seeking Shidduchim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some prayers that are apparently meant to be recited on Tu B'Av.  I in no way endorse this practice or these specific websites:

From https://www.hidabroot.org/article/71493:

**Shelah Hakadosh's Tefillah for finding a Zivug:**

> "יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ, יְיָ אֱלֹהַי וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתַי, שֶׁתַּמְצִיא לִי בְּרַחֲמֶיךָ הָרַבִּים וּבַחֲסָדֶיךָ הַגְּדוֹלִים אֶת זִוּוּגִי הָרָאוּי לִי בִּזְמַנּוֹ. זִוּוּג הָגוּן הָרָאוּי לְהוֹלִיד תַּלְמִיד חָכָם, גָּדוֹל בְּתוֹרָה וּבְיִרְאָה, מִזֶּרַע צַדִּיקִים וְאַנְשֵׁי אֱמֶת וִירְאֵי חֵטְא, כְּמוֹ שֶׁהִמְצֵאתָ זִוּוּגוֹ שֶׁל אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן, לְאַבְרָהָם וְיִצְחָק וְיַעֲקֹב וּמֹשֶׁה, כָּל אֶחָד וְאֶחָד זִוּוּגוֹ בְּעִתּוֹ וּבִזְמַנּוֹ. וְאוֹתוֹ אִישׁ שֶׁתַּמְצִיא לִי לְזִוּוּגִי יְהֵא: אִישׁ טוֹב, אִישׁ נָאֶה בְּמַעֲשָׂיו וְנָאֶה בְּמַרְאֵהוּ, בַּעַל מַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים, בַּעַל חֵן, אִישׁ מַשְׂכִּיל וִירֵא אֱלֹהִים, רוֹדֵף צְדָקָה וְגוֹמֵל חֶסֶד.
>
> וְלֹא יְהֵא בּוֹ שׁוּם שֶׁמֶץ פְּסוּל וּמוּם וּפְגָם. וְלֹא יְהֵא כַּעֲסָן וְרַגְזָן, רַק יְהֵא בַּעַל עֲנָוָה וּנְמִיכוּת רוּחַ, בָּרִיא וּבַעַל כֹּחַ. וְאַל יְעַכֵּב אַכְזָרִיּוּת הַבְּרִיּוֹת וְשׂוֹנְאִים וּמַחְשְׁבוֹתֵיהֶם וְתַחְבּוּלוֹתֵיהֶם וּמוֹעֲצוֹתֵיהֶם, לְעַכֵּב אֶת בֶּן זוּגִי הַהוּכַן לִי. וִיקֻיָּם בִּי מִקְרָא שֶׁכָּתוּב, לֹא יָנוּחַ שֵׁבֶט הָרֶשָׁע עַל גּוֹרַל הַצַּדִּיקִים, וּמִקְרָא שֶׁכָּתוּב, אֶשְׁתְּךָ כְּגֶפֶן פֹּרִיָּה בְּיַרְכְּתֵי בֵּיתֶךָ, בָּנֶיךָ כִּשְׁתִּילֵי זֵיתִים סָבִיב לְשֻׁלְחָנְךָ. כִּי אַתָּה הוּא הַמּוֹשִׁיב יְחִידִים בַּיְתָה מוֹצִיא אֲסִירִים בַּכּוֹשָׁרוֹת. יִהְיוּ לְרָצוֹן אִמְרֵי פִי וְהֶגְיוֹן לִבִּי לְפָנֶיךָ, יְיָ צוּרִי וְגוֹאֲלִי"

**Rav Elimelech Milezhensk's Tefillah for the above:**

> "יהי רצון מלפניך אבינו שבשמים, שתכין לבנו לראות הטוב שבחיים. וזרוק עלינו מי טהרה, לבטל מקרבנו צער וייאוש וכל מחשבה רעה, ותחת זה נזכה ללב שלם וטהור, מלא אמונה ושמחה, תקווה ואור. ולא נרגיש עצמנו חסרים וריקנים, המתאווים למלאות כל מיני מחסורים, אלא שבעים מטובך ותמיד מוכנים להשפיע מטובך על אחרים. ותעביר מעלינו כל המסכים, אשר בינינו לבינך מבדילים, ונזכה לחזור אליך בתשובה שלמה, ולתקן כל מה שקלקלנו מאז ועד עתה. ותיטע תמיד בליבנו יראתך ואהבה , ונשפוך ליבנו לפניך בעת התפילה. ותהא מחשבתנו זכה וצלולה וברורה, להבין עומק רצונך על ידי לימוד התורה, ונשתוקק רק להתקרב אליך, ולעשות את הטוב והישר בעיניך. ותעזרנו לסלוח ולאהוב את כולם, ולא נראה חסרונם ומומם. אדרבה, תן בליבנו , שנראה כל אחד מעלות חברינו, ולא יעלה על ליבנו חס ושלום שום שנאה אלא נשפיע לכולם רק הרבה רחמים ואהבה. אב הרחמן , תן בנו כח ובריאות לרוב, לעשות נחת רוח לפניך ולהיות אליך קרוב. "לב טהור ברא לי אלוהים ורוח נכון חדש בקרבי".

**Rabbi Nachman Mibreslev's Tefillah for the above:**

> "ריבונו של עולם, בחסדך יצרת עולמך, ובראת אדם, ועשית לו עזר, וציוויתנו לישא אישה ולהוליד בנים, והחמירו עבדיך רבותינו זיכרונם לברכה שלא לאחר מצווה זו, ויען חיי האדם בעולם הזה ובעולם הבא תלויים כמעט באשה, ובעונותינו הרבים אין עוד נביא ולא בעלי רוח- הקדש, לדעת איזו ראויה כדי לקיים מצוותיך. לכן בלב נשבר באתי להפיל תחנתי לפניך אב הרחמן, ויהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלוקי ואלוקי אבותיי שתתמלא רחמים עלי ותזמין לי בת- זוג נאה, יראת ה' ובעלת מדות טובות ובעלת מזל טוב, וטובת שכל ומוצלחת ומבורכת.
>
> כי בזה אוכל לעבוד עבודת הקדש בלי טרדה, והיה הנערה אשר ידברו לי עליה והיא ראויה, ויש לה יראת- ה' ומידות טובות ומזל טוב והוגנת לי, ברחמיך הרבים תחון עלי ותטה לבי לגמור הדבר באופן שאוכל לקיים מצוותיך וטוב לי בעולם הזה ובעולם הבא, אל מלא רחמים, ר'חום ח'נון ש'ומר ת'ומך מ'ציל י'שר פ'ודה, עזרני על דבר כבוד שמך. עשה למען שמך, עשה למען ימינך, עשה למען תורתך, עשה למען קדושתך. חנני וענני ושמע תפילתי כי אתה שומע תפילת כל פה, ברוך שומע תפילה. יהיו לרצון אמרי פי והגיון לבי לפניך, ה' צורי וגואלי. (Men)
>
> "יהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלוקי ואלוקי אבותי שתמציא לי ברחמיך הרבים ובחסדיך הגדולים את זווגי הראוי לי בזמנו,זווג הגון הראוי להוליד תלמיד חכם גדול בתורה וביראה,מזרע צדיקים ואנשי אמת ויראת חטא,כמו שהמצאת זווגו לאדם הראשון, לאברהם ויצחק ויעקב ומשה,כל אחד זווגו בעתו ובזמנו ואותו איש שתמציא לי לזיווגי יהא: איש טוב,איש נאה במעשיו,בעל מעשים טובים,בעל חן,איש משכיל וירא אלוהים,רודף צדקה וגומל חסד. ולא יהא בו שמץ פסול,ומום ופגם,ולא יהא כעסן ורגזן,רק בעל ענוה ונמיכות רוח,בריא ובעל כח,ואל יעכב אכזריות הבריות ושונאים ומסיבותיהם ותחבולותיהם לעכב את בן זוגי שהוכן לי,יהי לרצון אמרי פי והגיון לבי לפניך,ה' צורי וגואלי". (Women)

[Here](https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4108620,00.html)'s something a bit lighter.  [Here](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%95-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91/)'s something that is probably the best actual set of Tefillos for Tu B'Av.